# How to load a string list in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I have a list which has 100 elements, it looks like

```
"ENSG00000223972.4"
"ENSG00000227232.4"
"ENSG00000243485.2"
"ENSG00000237613.2"
"ENSG00000268020.2"
"ENSG00000240361.1"
```

I want to load this list in Matlab and I tried

```
x = load('list.txt');
```

But it shows an error that said "Unknown text of list.txt "ENSG00000223972.4".

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: It has the quotes in it? Then I think this could be read as a CSV file with one column. Use `readcell` if you have a recent version of MATLAB. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readcell.html

Answer (score 0):

The `load` function is not capable of importing data like this so the textscan function is needed instead.

Using the Import Wizard with a data file like this, it is capable of generating the below function to import the data

```
function file = importfile(filename, startRow, endRow)
%IMPORTFILE Import numeric data from a text file as a matrix.
%   FILE = IMPORTFILE(FILENAME) Reads data from text file FILENAME for the
%   default selection.
%
%   FILE = IMPORTFILE(FILENAME, STARTROW, ENDROW) Reads data from rows
%   STARTROW through ENDROW of text file FILENAME.
%
% Example:
%   file = importfile('file.txt', 1, 6);
%
%    See also TEXTSCAN.

% Auto-generated by MATLAB on 2021/09/20 16:03:26

%% Initialize variables.
delimiter = {''};
if nargin<=2
    startRow = 1;
    endRow = inf;
end

%% Read columns of data as text:
% For more information, see the TEXTSCAN documentation.
formatSpec = '%q%[^\n\r]';

%% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');



%% Read columns of data according to the format.
% This call is based on the structure of the file used to generate this
% code. If an error occurs for a different file, try regenerating the code
% from the Import Tool.
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow(1)-startRow(1)+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'TextType', 'string', 'HeaderLines', startRow(1)-1, 'ReturnOnError', false, 'EndOfLine', '\r\n');
for block=2:length(startRow)
    frewind(fileID);
    dataArrayBlock = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow(block)-startRow(block)+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'TextType', 'string', 'HeaderLines', startRow(block)-1, 'ReturnOnError', false, 'EndOfLine', '\r\n');
    dataArray{1} = [dataArray{1};dataArrayBlock{1}];
end

%% Close the text file.
fclose(fileID);

%% Convert the contents of columns containing numeric text to numbers.
% Replace non-numeric text with NaN.
raw = repmat({''},length(dataArray{1}),length(dataArray)-1);
for col=1:length(dataArray)-1
    raw(1:length(dataArray{col}),col) = mat2cell(dataArray{col}, ones(length(dataArray{col}), 1));
end
numericData = NaN(size(dataArray{1},1),size(dataArray,2));


%% Split data into numeric and string columns.
rawNumericColumns = {};
rawStringColumns = string(raw(:, 1));


%% Create output variable
file = rawStringColumns;
```

A rather long winded way to do it but it is robust to many different types of errors with the data like missing data.

Comment: @Heinkehdsk does the length of the function really matter? By having it as a separate function, you don't need all this complexity in the main part of your code. As I've updated the question to state, `load` won't work with ASCII data formatted like this. If you want to do it without this code, try using `textscan`.